# Generically print a sequence of variables with their names

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

I would like to:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
// ...

PRINT1(a, b, ...);
PRINT2(a, b, ...);
```

where `PRINT1` should expand to:

```
std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ... << std::endl;
// note: in "a = ...", "a" is the name of the variable, i.e.:
// PRINT(bar, ...) should print "bar = ..."
```

and `PRINT2` should expand to (using cppformat):

```
fmt::print("a = {}, b = {}, ...", a, b, ...);
```

Right now i'm using the Boost.PP and have to write `PRINT((a)(b)(c)...)` to achieve something similar to the first scenario, but it would be better if I could just use commas instead. A solution to one of the problems can probably be easily adapted to solve both.

Comment: So you basically want a function that takes an undefined amount of variables of undefined types and make it print out the content of the variable as well as their identifier-name?
Can you elaborate a little further why exactly? This sounds like nothing anyone should ever really want to do.

Comment: @Mercious debug_print(foo, bar, baz, a, b, c); would print to wherever you have configured it the name and value of each variable. Really useful when debugging, in particular when debugging optimized builds, builds without debug information, distributed systems where you cannot have a debugger session per process open (think of 10ks processes), ... Of course you can write the whole line yourself every time, but why should you? The preprocessor knows the name of the variable (#), and the compiler knows its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ` to convert it to a sequence, like so:

```
#define PRINT_ARGS(...) PRINT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Not very dynamic, you have to know beforehand how many arguments you are going to have:

```
// Using macros:

#define PRINT1_1(A)   std::cout << "a = " << A << std::endl;
#define PRINT1_2(A,B) std::cout << "a = " << A << ", b = " << B << std::endl;

#define PRINT2_1(A)   fmt::print("a = {}", A);
#define PRINT2_2(A,B) fmt::print("a = {}, b = {}", A, B);

// Using `va_arg`:

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

void PRINT1(int argc, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, argc);
    char vc = 'a';
    int val = argc;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i, ++vc) {
        std::cout << vc << " = " << va_arg(args, int);
        if (i < argc - 1)
            std::cout << ", ";
    }
    va_end(args);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// similarly implement PRINT2

int main()
{
    PRINT1_2(1,2);

    // first argument specifies the number
    // of the remaining arguments:
    PRINT1(3, 1,2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1, b = 2
a = 1, b = 2, c = 4
```

Comment: a and b are the name of the variables, PRINT1(foo, bar, baz) should print "foo = ..., bar = ..., baz = ...". I added a remark to the question to emphasize this.

Comment: @gnzlbg Stack Overflow isn't a 'code for me' site, it does not serve to provide code in the manner that is specific to your program. You can change the variable names.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ 1)This is a general recurring problem. 2) I already have a solution to this problem using Boost.PP (am asking for better, different one that does not have the problem mentioned). I don't know what you mean with "you can change the variable names",  svlasov didn't understood the question I posed, which is fine, I guess that is partially my fault. I've tried to improve the question by adding a note. But note that the title says"generically print a sequence of variables (i.e. their values) with their names (i.e. the corresponding name of each variable).